# SQL Developer, Java 1.7.0_07 error

Tags: java, version, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, while trying to open Oracle SQL Developer on my Windows 7 machine, I get the following error:

```
You are attempting to run with Java 1.7.0_07

Running this product is supported with a minimum Java
version of 1.6.0_04 and a maximum version less than 1.7.

This product will not be supported, and may not run correctly
if you proceed. Continue anyway?
```

[image: This is how it looks like]

The version of Java on my computer, according to the Verify Java Version link (http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) is **Version 7 Update 7** AND there is a newer version available, which i am reluctant to download, considering the error I receive.

Via CMD, when I try to check the version, this is what I see:

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And the problem is...

Comment: Try to update Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Got a workaround. Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run `Oracle SQL Developer` which is (as per the current version you are having) expecting `JRE version` to be **< 1.7** or **7**

Your JRE version is `JRE 1.7.x.`

To solve this problem, you can either install `JRE 1.6.x` and **uninstall** `JRE 1.7`

OR

Wait for the new release of Oracle SQL Developer which supports `JRE 1.7`

BTW, its a *warning*. With your own risk, you can say "Yes" to that dialog and run. Since Java is backward compatible, `JRE 1.`7 should be able to run a code developed with `JDK 1.6`

Comment: Thnx a ton sanbhat. Will keep that in mind :)